# How to do some jobs when reached fixed time points which are in an array of datetime?

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

Say that I Have an array of datetime :

```
$array = ['a' => '2016-12-03 18:00:00', 'b' => '2016-12-03 18:23:00']
```

How can I do something when the time from the array has reached?

For example: at time `$array['a']`, I have to send a email, and at time `$array['b']`,
I have to send another email.

Actually the array is very large, about 10'0000 elements.

Comment: I think you need to use cron jobs for that

Comment: Instead of a long-running php script, you are probably better off scheduling jobs in cron (on linux...) and using a task queue to keep track of what needs to get done and when. So dump your array in a database and check every xx minutes what jobs need executing.

Comment: @jeroen I afraid that it may add too much work load to database.

Comment: One database call every xx minutes? That is very unlikely. Keeping a very large array in memory in a long-running php script probably has a (lot...) bigger impact on system performance.